# Not able to fetch all records with dates condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have the following sql statement where I am trying to get records, the problem is I am not able to get one record even though the date is matching.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d721/2)

```
SELECT distinct  vname,start_date
FROM   my_dates
where 
 start_date >= to_date('30-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') 
and start_date <= to_date('06-MAY-2013','DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
```

What am I doing wrong with my query?

Comment: My eyeballs tell me that your date format picture does not match the format of the date you are using.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Even if I remove HH12:MI:SS AM from query I am not able to get the last row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't specify the hours, minutes or seconds in the TO_DATE portion of your criteria statement, Oracle defaults to 00:00:00, so your statement basically says to look for values where the `start_date is between "30-APR-2013 00:00:00 AM" AND "06-MAY-2013 00:00:00 AM"`.  Since "06-MAY-2013 6:59:00 AM" is outside this range, it is not returned in the results.  Here are a couple ways you can fix this:

Specify the hours, minutes and seconds in your TO_DATE statement to include the entire day on the back end of the date range.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  vname,start_date
  FROM my_dates
 WHERE start_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('30-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') 
                      AND TO_DATE('06-MAY-2013 11:59:59 PM','DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
```

Alternately you can do a calculation to add 23 hours, 59 minutes and 59 seconds to the 2nd date value to do the same thing as above.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  vname,start_date
  FROM my_dates
 WHERE start_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('30-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY') 
                      AND TO_DATE('06-MAY-2013','DD-MON-YYYY')+1-(1/24/60/60)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Second approach will be dynamic so that I do not need to hardcode the parameter? Real scenario is I am getting date parameters from front end application which would only pass the date, not minutes and seconds.

Comment: Yes, the second option is a clean way to do it if you only receive the date and not the hours, minutes or seconds.  It will automatically add 23:59:59 to the 2nd date, so any start_date that occurred any time during the 2nd date will also be included in your result set.

Answer (score 0):

`to_date('06-MAY-2013','DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')` will return  `May, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000` which is less than `06-MAY-2013 6:59:00 AM','DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM` Because of this your are not getting the last row.
Try  this query...

```
SELECT distinct  vname,start_date
FROM   my_dates
where 
 start_date >= to_date('30-APR-2013','DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') 
and to_char(start_date,'DD.MM.YYYY')  <= to_char(start_date,'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

[Sql fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d721/27)

Comment: Amit, even if I remove `HH12:MI:SS AM` from query I am not able to get the last row

Comment: @AmitSingh, Why is that second condition in the query required? It is not doing anything. Also, comparing the date after converting to varchar is not correct.

Comment: @Noel see the sql fiddle friend it gives all the result.......and about second conditiom its is used bcz it might have more values ok...hope it clears u all

Comment: @AmitSingh, the first condition alone is sufficient for returning all the rows. the second condition is true for all cases.

Comment: @Noel what will it return when you have may 7....the OP doesnt want to retrive all data he want to know why his query is not returning may 6 intead of using second condtiton pls read question carefully..and try to understand OP problem my friend

Comment: @Noel the OP orginal query is not to retrive all rows but he wana know why he not geting last row instead of using second condtion ok.......if u can not understand than its ur problem..not my query